# Scala: Why can I convert Int to Unit?

Tags: scala, unit-type

I've recently started playing with Scala (2.8) and noticed the I can write the following code (in the Scala Interpreter):

```
scala> var x : Unit = 10
x : Unit = ()
```

It's not obvious what's going on there. I really didn't expect to see any implicit conversion to **Unit**.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

See section *"6.26.1 Value Conversions"* in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf#page=104) version 2.8:

...

**Value Discarding.** If `e` has some value type and the expected type is Unit, `e` is converted
to the expected type by embedding it in the term `{ e; () }`.

...

Comment: Note that you can make a warning for this by using `scalacOptions += "-Ywarn-value-discard"` in SBT configuration.

Answer (score 15):

Anything can be converted to Unit.  This is mostly necessary to support side-effecting methods which nonetheless return values, but where the return value is often ignored.  For instance

```
import java.util.{List =>JList}

def remove2[A](foo: JList[A], a1:A, a2:A):Unit = {
    foo.remove(a1)
    foo.remove(a2)  //if you couldn't convert the (usually pointless) return value of remove to Unit, this wouldn't type
}
```

Comment: It's not really *necessary*, though if you usually want to ignore return values it is more convenient than doing so explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

Well, anything can be converted to unit (which is its purpose). You can think of Unit as unit in the lattice of (sub)types, which means it is a supertype of everything. See [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type).

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you mean here: Unit is not actually the least element of the type lattice in Scala, which is the type Any.
Unit does not actually have any subtypes in Scala as far as I can tell, it is defined as "final class Unit extends AnyVal".

mkneissl's answer above seems to give the real reason this works - implicit conversion.

Did you mean something specific in saying it the lattice of (sub)types?