# Why can I assign null to a Unit value and why does it get converted to ()?

Tags: class, scala, null, unit-type

Consider this code:

```
var unit: Unit = null
unit: Unit = ()
```

a) Why am I allowed to assign null to a value class? (see §12.2.3)

b) Why does the `null` get converted to `()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala: Why can I convert Int to Unit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513364/scala-why-can-i-convert-int-to-unit)

Comment: Where do you see that `()` gets converted to null?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the scala specification section 6.26.1:

> **Value Discarding.** If `e` has some value type and the expected type is `Unit`, `e` is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term `{ e ; () }`.

In other words, your code is equivalent to

```
var unit: Unit = {null; ()}
unit: Unit = ()
```

The `null` isn't converted -- it's merely ignored and replaced by `()`, the predefined `Unit` value.