# Why the following scala code is valid?

Tags: scala

My understanding is `Unit` = `void`, but why I can pass in multiple argument?

So can anyone explain why the following code is valid?

```
def foo(x: Unit) = println("foo")                 
foo("ss", 1)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a parameter of type Unit?   If you don't want a parameter then just do `def foo()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you run your snippet with `scala -print` you'll roughly get the following output for the code:

```
/* Definition of foo */
private def foo(x: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit): Unit = {

/* Invocation of foo */
foo({
  new Tuple2("ss", scala.Int.box(1));
  scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
});
```

As you can see, the arguments to `foo` are rewritten into a code block that creates a tuple but then returns UNIT.

I can't see a good reason for this behaviour and I'd rather get a compiler error thrown instead.

Comment: If you define `foo(x: (String, Int))` then you can call it as above with a pair of arguments, which are automatically tupled.  Since anything can be passed in for `Unit`, it seems that the tuple conversion is appropriate in exactly the way you've demonstrated.  I'm not sure I like this either, but perhaps the fault lies with the auto-tupling in general?

Answer (score 5):

A related question which gives a decent answer to this is here:

[Scala: Why can I convert Int to Unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513364/scala-why-can-i-convert-int-to-unit)

From Section 6.26.1 of the [Scala Language Specification v2.9](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), "Value Discarding":

> If e has some value type and the expected type is Unit, e is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term { e; () }.

So, in your case it seems ("ss", 1) is being converted to a tuple so that it can be treated as a single argument, then as that argument type is not Unit, it is converted to a block which computes that tuple value then returns unit to match with the required type of the parameter.