# scala Future onComplete method signature understanding

Tags: scala

```
trait Future[T]{
    def onComplete( callback: Try[T] => Unit )(...):Unit
}

trait Socket{
    def sendToEurope( packet:Array[Byte] ):Future[Array[Byte]]
}

val c:Future[Array[Byte]] = packet onComplete {
    case Success(p) => socket.sendToEurope(p)
    ....
}
```

this a sample quoted from the class note of coursera "Reactive programming"

I was trying to understanding the method signature here. onComplete takes a Try => Unit function type, while the bracket section is a Success=>FutureType. I don't see how the 2 types are compatible here. Taking variance into consideration: Function1[-A,+R] which makes Success compatible, but I still don't see Future covariant with Unit here.

can someone explain this to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of the code is correct, that it does not compile.

Future.onComplete returns a Unit and therefore cannot return a Future[Array[Byte]] despite it being return type of socket.sendToEurope.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct.  Any value will be automatically converted to Unit if Unit is the expected type.  The rule is there for these types of situations, where otherwise you would have to do:

```
val c:Future[Array[Byte]] = packet onComplete {
    case Success(p) => socket.sendToEurope(p); ()
    ....
}
```

Which would be ugly.

See [Scala: Why can I convert Int to Unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513364/scala-why-can-i-convert-int-to-unit)

Comment: We are not converting here from "X" to Unit, but from Unit to "X", which is not possible.

Comment: I was referring to the *parameter* to the `onComplete` which I believe was the original question. But you are right about the value returned by `onComplete` - it is `Unit`, not `Future`.