# Scala Try[Unit] confusion

Tags: scala, types, try-catch

I have this piece of code

```
import scala.util.Try
val t: Try[Unit] = Try(Try(1))
```

and 2 questions:

- What is happening here? How can the type `Try[Try[Int]]` match with
  `Try[Unit]`? Is it because Scala chooses the return type for block
  `Try(1)` to be `Unit` to match with the desired type?
- Is there anyway to detect a nested `Try`? Says I have a `Try[A]`, how do I know if `A` is another `Try[_]`?

Comment: If you ask the compiler to discard the value (i.e. type something as Unit explicitly), it will let you do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513647/14955

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You are basically forcing compiler to assign `Try` as `Unit`.**

For exmple `doSomething` method below is supposed to return `Int` as that is last statement, but return type `Unit` is forcing it to return `()`.

```
scala> def doSomething: Unit = 1 + 1
doSomething: Unit
```

**In your example `val t: Try[Unit] = Try(Try(1 / 0))`,** you asking compiler to treat inner `Try(1 / 0)` as `Unit`; which means

```
scala> val innerTry: Unit = Try(1 / 0)
innerTry: Unit = ()
```

Which means even if `Try` fails, its `Unit` which is always `Success` for another `Try` that you have.

```
scala> val t: Try[Unit] = Try(someOperation)
t: scala.util.Try[Unit] = Success(())
```

**Better remove the specific type you are providing and let the compiler figure it out,**

```
scala> val t = Try(Try(1 / 0))
t: scala.util.Try[scala.util.Try[Int]] = Success(Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero))
```

**Also read: [Scala: Why can I convert Int to Unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3513364/432903)**

```
final abstract class Unit private extends AnyVal {
  // Provide a more specific return type for Scaladoc
  override def getClass(): Class[Unit] = ???
}
```

Comment: about the 2nd question, how do I prevent this situation to happen? Says if I have a `Try[A]`, how do I know that `A` is not another `Try[_]`?

Answer (score 1):

`Try(1)` returns `Success(1)`.
`Try(Try(1)` returns `Success(())`because of its assignment to Type `Try[Unit]`
Similar to the following commands in Scala REPL where x is forced to take `Unit` type:

```
scala> val x = 5
x: Int = 5

scala> val x:Unit = 5
<console>:23: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
       val x:Unit = 5
                    ^
x: Unit = ()

scala>
```

So obviously the compiler is taking the return value and is forced to type `()` which is `Unit`.
Because it is `Unit` may be it makes sense the way compiler interprets it.